# Create a Java string form a linux command

Tags: java, linux, string, format

I have a linux command:

```
sudo su - -c "echo 'exit 1'> /usr/lib/ocf/resource.d/oom_check_ocf.bsh"
```

I want to create this command and store it into a string.

The end portion of the string will be a variable healthScript, such as

```
healthScript= /usr/lib/ocf/resource.d/oom_check_ocf.bsh
```

What I have tried:

```
"sudo su - -c"+" "echo 'exit 1' > +healthScript""
```

I am confused because the linux command has double quotes in it, which are used to wrap the executed command, which is:

```
echo 'exit 1'> /usr/lib/ocf/resource.d/oom_check_ocf.bsh
```

How do I write a string which has double quotes inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to escape ""

```
String healthScript="sudo su - -c \""+"echo 'exit 1'> /usr/lib/ocf/resource.d/oom_check_ocf.bsh\"";
    System.out.println(healthScript);
```

**output:**`sudo su - -c "echo 'exit 1'> /usr/lib/ocf/resource.d/oom_check_ocf.bsh"`